# Cambio de ruta de text custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

```
function deals_bh_visits() {

 $fichero = "visits_deals.txt";

 $fptr = fopen($fichero,"r");


 $num = fread($fptr,filesize($fichero));
 $num++;

 $fptr = fopen($fichero,"w+");
 fwrite($fptr,$num);
 fclose($fptr);
 return ("<span id='days_since'>$num</span>");
}
add_shortcode('deals_bh_visits', 'deals_bh_visits');
```

Tengo un problema, pero antes formulare lo que hace el siguiente codigo, este codigo crea un archivo text, con un numero que aumenta cada vez que recargue la web , dicho numero se muestra en donde se coloque el shortcode.

Tengo un solo problema, y es que el archivo no se crea en la misma carpeta de donde esta el plugin, se crea en la raiz de la web. como puedo hacer para cambiar la ruta del text y se cree en el mismo lugar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El plugin se ejecuta mediante un include de la ruta que despliega el archivo, en este caso `/index.php`. Como ese es el entrypoint de todas las vistas de una plantilla, el shortcode siempre se ejecuta como parte de ese script.

Para lo que quieres hacer, podrías ocupar la función `plugin_dir_path` ([documentación WP](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/)) que se ocupa de la siguiente manera:

```
$dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ); 

$fichero = $dir. "visits_deals.txt";

$fptr = fopen($fichero,"r");
```

Y con eso el archivo se creará en la forma:

```
/home/user/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/visit_deals.txt
```

Dicho esto... estás seguro de que quieres generar un nuevo archivo por cada visita? No se volverá un poco inmanejable apenas tengas un par de centenares de hits?

Comment: Muchas gracias ! @amenadiel

Comment: como puedo colocar si quiero colocar ese txt, en una carpeta de ese plugin?

Comment: primero creas la carpeta a mano y luego `$fichero = $dir. "carpeta/visits_deals.txt";` También puedes crearla en el código, pero para qué complicarnos, digo yo.